# Trying to concatenate read data in Python loop but receiving error

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, formatting, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate the data being read from a text file (a single number which is updated as the loop iterates) into the name of the file.  Making a copy of the file each time around and iterating the copy number.  The reason for the read file is I would like to be able to pick up where I left off, but I keep running into this error:

> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

I have tried moving the str() operator to several different areas but cannot seem to find the sweet spot that will make the Python gods happy...code follows and we are looking at the copy_loop function toward the bottom, though for completeness I have included all of it:

```
from shutil import copyfile
import time
import tkinter as tk
import threading


class App():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.isrunning = False

        self.button1 = tk.Button(main, text='start')
        self.button1.bind ("<Button-1>", self.startrunning)
        self.button1.pack()

        self.button2 = tk.Button(main, text='stop')
        self.button2.bind ("<Button-1>", self.stoprunning)
        self.button2.pack()

    def startrunning(self, event=None):
        self.isrunning = True
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.copy_loop)
        t.start()

    def stoprunning(self, event=None):
        self.isrunning = False

    def copy_loop(self):
        read_file = open("loop_counter.txt", "r")
        iteration = read_file.read()
        i = iteration # why can't I make you a string???????!!!!!!!!!!!
        while self.isrunning:
            copyfile("TestFile.docx", "TestFile(" + str(i+1) + ").docx")
            print("File has been duplicated " + str(i+1) + " times.")
            i += 1
            time.sleep(restTime)
            iteration = open("loop_counter.txt", "w")
            iteration.write(str(i))


restTime = int(5)
main = tk.Tk()
app = App(main)
main.mainloop()
```

I appreciate any help you can offer.

EDIT:  Closing the file:

```
    With iteration:
        iteration.write(str(i))
        iteration.close()
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem isn't that you're failing to make `i` into a string. It's that it already *is* a string, even before you try—and therefore, adding `1` to it is illegal.

First, you `read` it from a file. This always returns a `str`:

```
iteration = read_file.read()
i = iteration # why can't I make you a string???????!!!!!!!!!!!
```

Then, you try to add 1 to that string in multiple places, each of which will give you a `TypeError`:

```
copyfile("TestFile.docx", "TestFile(" + str(i+1) + ").docx")
print("File has been duplicated " + str(i+1) + " times.")
i += 1
```

To fix this, convert the string to an int right after you read it, like this:

```
i = int(iteration)
```

Then, the rest of your code will work, because the rest of your code is all expecting `i` to be an int.

However, you should consider simplifying it by using string formatting instead of manually converting things to strings and concatenating them. For example, this is a lot easier to read, and harder to get wrong:

```
copyfile("TestFile.docx", f"TestFile({i+1}).docx")
```

Or, if you have to work with older versions of Python:

```
copyfile("TestFile.docx", "TestFile({}).docx".format(i+1))
```

Comment: Brilliant.  One more thing, is the final line of the loop redundant?  Where I write: 
'iteration.write(str(i))' ? Sorry, not sure why my mini-Markdown didn't work...

Comment: @sonofajay We only get limited markdown in comments. In particular, you can use backticks to format inline code fragments, but there's no way to write code blocks.

Comment: @sonofajay Anyway, I don't know if it's redundant. Rewriting the file every time might be useful if you're trying to make it so that if your program crashes you can pick up where you left off on the next run. If you weren't trying to do anything like that, then… I'd have to know why you wrote those lines to know whether they're redundant.

Comment: @sonofajay Two side notes: (1) It's very confusing to reuse the same variable name `iteration` to mean two completely different things—the contents of the file in one place, then a file object for the file in another. (2) It's a bad idea to not `close` your files, especially ones you're write to, even more especially if you might want to read them later in the same program. Generally you just want to use a `with` statement to take care of that automatically.

Comment: Thanks again.  The line is there for the exact purpose you stated with the caveat that I want it to pick up again whether the program crashes or is shutdown along with the computer for any reason.  I just meant is it redundant to call the i variable a str during that write process?  As for closing the file, I'm going to add what I think you mean as an edit to the op since a block will be easier to read.

Comment: @sonofajay The `write` method requires strings, so the `str(i)` is not ambiguous there. (Of course you could use string formatting again, or you could `print(i, file=iteration)`, or something else, but here, using `str` makes sense.)

Answer (score 0):

It is simply because `i` is string and `1` is integer in your case. All you need to do is to use `str(int(i)+1)` to turn `i` into integer before adding up with 1, and then change the entire integer into string again.